# Ошибка при парсинге: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.olx.ua/list/q-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81/?search%5Bpaidads_listing%5D=1'
headers = {
    'user-Agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
    'accept':
    'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#print(req)
src = req.text

all_videocards = {}

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
all_links_videocards = soup.find_all('a', class_='marginright5')


#print(all_links_videocards)
for item in all_links_videocards:
    item_text = item.text.strip()
    item_href = item.get('href')
    #print(f"{item_text}: {item_href}")
    all_videocards[item_text] = item_href
print(all_videocards)

count = 0

for  product_name, product_href in all_videocards.items():
    page_req = requests.get(url=product_href, headers=headers)
    src = page_req.text
    with open(f'C:/python/data/{count}_{product_name}.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(src)
    count+=1
```

Вото такая ошибка: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/python/data/6_Велосипед Горный Спортивный Azimut Power/ Scorpion 24/26" Двухподвес.html'
Подскажите если знаете в чем проблема

Comment: Проблема в том, что нет такого файла. Разве возможны какие то разночтения? А скорее всего папки или там нет прав на запись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ошибке `No such file or directory: 'C:/python/data/6_Велосипед Горный Спортивный Azimut Power/ Scorpion 24/26" Двухподвес.html` - у вас в `product_name` есть слэши. Ошибка возникает из-за того, что слэш считается разделителем пути, а не частью имени.

Т.е. `6_Велосипед Горный Спортивный Azimut Power` и  `Scorpion 24` будут считаться именами папок, в которых вы пытаетесь создать файл `26" Двухподвес.html`. Т.к. таких папок у вас нет, то возникает ошибка. Кавычки в части `24/26"`, также являются недопустимыми в имени.

Вариант решения - заменять слэши (и другие недопустимые символы) на что-то другое, например на подчеркивания:

```
product_name = product_name.replace('/', '_').replace('\\', '_').replace('"', '_')
with open(f'C:/python/data/{count}_{product_name}.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(src)
```

Замена через регулярные выражения (в квадратных скобках в регулярном выражении нужно перечислить все недопустимые символы):

```
import re

...

product_name = re.sub(r'[/\\"]', '_', product_name)
```